# Software for home network streaming a desktop PC to a laptop

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I'm looking to create a remote desktop setup in my home where I can grab a cheap, low-end laptop, plug an ethernet cable connected to my home network, and stream Monitor 1 (with the option to switch between other monitors) with little-to-no latency. I'll be using Windows 10 on both the desktop and laptop.

The reason I want to do this is because I can't stand the heat and fan noise my high-end laptop produces when trying to work/play games in bed or on the sofa.

So I'm looking for low-latency software that I can use to remote into my desktop PC through my own home network, hardwired through ethernet. I don't care about wifi or remoting in from outside my network at another location through the internet.

I've only ever tried Teamviewer and only through the internet, so I'm not sure if it can remote through local network. The experience I had with Teamviewer doing anything but editing text (like playing games) was absolutely abysmal and unusable, so I can only assume it's not much different even when hardwired locally.

If good software exists that can remote me into my PC through a laptop, then I can go ahead and buy a cheap laptop, probably with a decent network card to minimize latency as much as possible.

EDIT: I've seen someone suggest using HDMI if the computer is really close. While I can do this, I've never seen a laptop capable of HDMI in, only HDMI out.

Answer (score 1):

Use "spacedesk" it should work.
the software is free.
I believe its the best. because It supports mobile phones too.
That's a youtube link. it shows how to set it up.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSh9EV35BMI&t=274s
https://spacedesk.net/

Pls. let us know if you encounter any problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use software to do this
Easily connect two systems to a modem with a router
Make remote descktop settings on the destination system

[image]

Then connect to the desired system via the internal ip, which will also have a good image transfer speed because it is an internal network

You can find the desired system ip in the Windows network setting section